# How to run php-fpm in docker-compose.yml?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I tried to build a container used docker-compose. So I wrote the dockerfile and docker-compose.yml like following:

**dockerfile**

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y expect
RUN apt-get -y install software-properties-common 
RUN apt-add-repository ppa:ondrej/php
RUN apt-get -y install php7.1 php7.1-fpm 
RUN apt-get install php7.1-mysql
RUN apt-get -y install nginx
RUN apt-get -y install vim
COPY default /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
COPY www.conf /etc/php/7.1/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
COPY test /var/www/html/test
CMD service php7.1-fpm start && nginx -g "daemon off;"
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
   web:
     build: 
       context: .
       dockerfile: Dockerfile
     ports:
       - "3011:80"
```

When I run following command, the php7.1-fpm is run success.

```
docker-compose build
docker-compose up --force-recreate -d
```

But I want to move the CMD from dockerfile to docker-compose, so I changed the file like following:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
command: service php7.1-fpm start && nginx -g "daemon off;"
```

But this time php7.1-fpm is not running.

How to fix this issue, so that I can run php7.1-fpm in docker-compose.yml?

Comment: The solution is simple, don't run two processes inside a single container. A container is not a virtual machine. A container is a **process**. Use two containers: `web` for nginx and `php` for the php-fpm. It's pretty straightforward, there are many working examples to be found on StackOverflow. Been there, done that, thought it's easier to run everything inside a single container, it's not.

Comment: Okay, I will try it. Thanks your advice.

Answer (score -1):

- you can not use `service php7.1-fpm start` in your Dockerfile, because container is just a process, not a real virtual machine, main process down and others will down neither
- docker suggest you to divide them in different container, php-fpm, nginx, single image single container
- solution:
  docker/php-fpm/Dockerfile

  `FROM php:7.2-fpm
  RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql mbstring`

  docker-compose.yml:

  `version: '2.1'
  services:
  nginx:
      image: nginx:latest
      ports:
        - 8001:80
      volumes:
          - ./:/app
          # nginx configs
          - ./docker/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
  php-fpm:
      build: ./docker/php-fpm
      volumes:
          - ./:/app
  php-composer:
      restart: 'no'
      image: composer
      volumes:
          - ./:/app
      command: install
  nodejs:
      restart: 'no'
      image: node:8.9
      volumes:
          - ./:/app
      command: /bin/bash -c "cd /app && npm install && npm run prod"
  networks:
  default:`